# target a <li> so that you can click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently developing a program. It includes a 3 option navigation bar. It uses `<li>` and does not have id's, when i try to add id's to them it messes up the order, and doesent even work with a click! Im starting to loose faith with it.. can anyone help me on this one,

**my GOAL is** to have it alert different things on different clicks, so than I could link different html pages,

fiddle used [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1swep9oq/).

```
<ul class="ui-module menu-selector" id="menu-selector">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li class="js-is-active">Notif's</li>
  <li>Profile</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is not working in your fiddle ? Everything seem to work properly ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate (or even better, demonstrate in a snippet or a fiddle) on "when i try to add id's to them it messes up the order"? IDs should have zero effect on element order.

Comment: When I added the Id's it would take away the click function, which dimmed the selected item, When you click on the profile button I want it to alert you, "Profile has been clicked" And same for the rest. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have ids, I suppose that `childNodes` property will help a lot.

For example, you can use:

```
var lis = document.getElementById('menu-selector').childNodes; 
// or you can select lis directly...
// var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-selector li');

Array.prototype.slice.call(lis)
  .forEach(function(li) {
    // do something... like
    li.onclick = function () {
      console.log(this);
    }
  });
```

Note: `childNodes` (or `querySelectorAll` return) is [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) type, and I use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` in order to use `forEach()` method on it.

See [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) for more details.

Comment: How could I determine what is being clicked with this method, thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Nick In this solution, I add one `onclick` method for every li element, so I can just use `this` to refer to the element self. You can try to run the code and log `this` and you'll see the element.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to have ids on your li elements for some reason you can use the following logic to select active `li`:

`$("#menu-selector li.active").on("click", function(){
            alert($(this).text())
});`

Answer (score 0):

I added id's for you, not sure what you meant by it messing up the order.

HTML

```
<div class="ui-items">
    <header class="ui-module app-header">VoiceBox <a href="#" class="app-header__btn app-header__btn--friends"><i class="entypo-user-add"></i></a>
 <a href="#" class="app-header__btn app-header__btn--edit"><i class="entypo-pencil"></i></a>

    </header>
    <div id="outer">
        <ul class="ui-module menu-selector" id="menu-selector">
            <li id="home_li">Home</li>
            <li id="notif_li" class="js-is-active">Notif's</li>
            <li id="profile_li">Profile</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var listItem = $('#menu-selector > li');

$(listItem).click(function() {
  $(listItem).removeClass('js-is-active');
  $(this).toggleClass('js-is-active');

});

$('#home_li').click(function(){
   alert('home clicked')
})

$('#notif_li').click(function(){
   alert('notifs clicked')
})

$('#profile_li').click(function(){
   alert('profile clicked')
})
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1swep9oq/2/